# Orientation Change Not Being Detected in Android Tablets

Tags: android, cordova, jquery-mobile

I currently have this code(and I've tried various others) at the bottom of my app for detecting orientation change:

```
function orientation_changed (){
    if ( is_portrait() )
    {
        alert('ABC');
    }
    else if ( is_landscape() )
    {
        alert('234');
    }
    clearTimeout(window.t);
    delete window.t;
}

window.t = undefined;
window.onorientationchange = function (event)
{
    window.t = setTimeout('orientation_changed();', 250);
}

function is_landscape()
{
    var uagent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
    if ( uagent.search('ipad') > -1 )
    {
        var r = ( window.orientation == 90 || window.orientation == -90 );
    }
    else
    {
        var r = ( screen.width > screen.height );
    }
    return r;
}

function is_portrait()
{
    var uagent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
    if ( uagent.search('ipad') > -1 )
    {
        var r = ( window.orientation == 0 || window.orientation == 180 );
    }
    else
    {
        var r = ( screen.width < screen.height );
    }
    return r;
}
```

But it never fires. I've tried other ways of getting the change in orientation of my tablet but none seem to work. My manifest looks like this:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
      package="com.pp.editable" android:versionName="1.1" android:versionCode="5" android:hardwareAccelerated="true">
    <supports-screens
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true"
        android:resizeable="true"
        android:anyDensity="true"
        />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_VIDEO"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />   
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />   
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />


    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:debuggable="true">
        <activity android:name="editabledelights" android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"
                android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" android:targetSdkVersion="17"/>
</manifest>
```

And I am using a Lenovo IdeaPad. I'm using JQuery mobile and Cordova 2.3.0. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3):

This is because you have added "sceenSize" attribute just remove that

Answer (score 1):

I feel dumb. On Lenovo, its set to portrait only in the system setting :P. Had to enable orientation switching.

Answer (score 0):

you are probably forgetting to add the event listener for detecting the orientation change.

```
// attach the onOrientationChange event listener in your script tag
window.addEventListener( 'onorientationchange', OnOrientationChange, false );
```

Hope that helps.